# Regular expression optimization - C enum typedef

Tags: python, regex

For a certain project of mine I need to parse enum typedefs from an .h file.
For example lets take the next simple case:

```
typedef enum
{
    data1, /*aaagege*/
    data2,

    data3
}ESample;
```

This is a very simple declaration (without assigns or anything a bit more complex) and yet the regular expression that I wrote seems to be very poor performance wise.
Here is my expression:

```
typedef\s+enum\s*\{(?:\s+(\w+)[^\n]*)+\s*\}(\w+)\s*;
```

I've tested the expression on one of my files (about 2000 lines of code) and it took ages..
The first thing that I tried to do is to make everything possible not greedy like so:

```
typedef\s+?enum\s*?\{(?:\s+?(\w+?)[^\n]*?)+?\s*?\}(\w+?)\s*?;
```

But that only made things worse.
Any suggestions as to how I can make this better performance wise? If you could add an explanation about your suggested solution and why it is better than mine It will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance,
Kfir

Comment: Why would making it not greedy make it faster? (Also, why is this tagged C and C++? It's only tangentally related to C and C++, since I assume the regex is being used in Python.)

Comment: Apologies, removed the redundant tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's slow is because of your nested repeats (marked with ^):

```
(?:\s+(\w+)[^\n]*)+
                ^ ^
```

This causes nested backtracking, which leads to exponential running times.

But you have a larger problem which is that putting a group inside a repeat means that only the last match of the group is kept:

```
>>> print m.groups()
('data3', 'ESample')
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP only really wants the group at the end containing the `typedef`ed name, but +1 for noticing that. If (s)he wants to get the `enum` values it'll probably require a second (looping) pass.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the matches? (A flag or something similar..)

Comment: I think you can solve both your problems by using one regex to get the inside of the braces, and another to parse out the enum names.

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse C with a regex:

```
// w00t /* "testing */ "strings n comments \"here"//
printf("/* haha gotcha\" epic stuff") /* "more text // */;

/* typedef test {
     val,
     "string",
*/ typedef test ??<
     val,
     "commentstring/*\"//",
??>
```

But if you just want a quick hack to parse all the typedefs:

```
typedef\s+enum\s*{[^}]*}[^;]+;
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to parse C with a regex, just a few C declarations. (Perhaps a parser should be used, but your first example isn't a good way to show that for this case, and your second example is horribly contrived.)

Comment: None of these are valid concerns. There will _never_ be strings in an `enum` body (and only rarely comments), no one will _ever_ use trigraphs except on legacy code (in which case the OP would know how to handle it), and you're just jumping through hoops to construct the most artificially regex-breaking "examples" possible. The OP is probably looking for a quick hack, and one is easily possible for such a limited set of input, but you're ignoring that entirely.

Answer (score 2):

> The first thing that I tried to do is to make everything possible not gready... But that only made things worse.

Of course it did! How couldn't it? Look a this regex:

```
\w+\s
```

It will (greedily) eat up all the word characters, and when those are out, it will look for a space character. Now consider:

```
\w+?\s
```

This eats up one word character, then checks for a space. Failing that, it eats another word character and checks for a space. It checks *every word character* to see if it's a space.

Generally, non-greedy is slower than greedy because it has to check the same characters twice. Sometimes, non-greedy produces different results, but when it doesn't, *always* use greedy. In fact, Perl has *possessive* quantifiers:

```
\w++\s
```

Which means "be greedy, and if that fails to match don't bother giving any characters back because you're too greedy." The example above works fine, and may be optimizable, but you can really understand it with this:

```
\w++h
```

That example will always fail, because any "h" character at the end of a word will get permanently eaten up by `\w++`, whereas if it was just `\w+` it'd get eaten up, but then given back once the match failed once to see if it would succeed.

Unfortunately Python doesn't have the possessive form to my knowledge (though in the comments, @tchrist suggests an alterative Python regex library), so the first example is about as fast as I suspect you'll get. You might also find a speedup by searching for occurrences of the string "enum" and working from there instead of using a single giant regex to search through an entire file.

Comment: Perl and Java call things like `\w++` “possessive” quantifiers. These are shortcuts for “atomic grouping”: `\w++` is exactly equivalent to `(?>\w+)`, which is a nonbracktracking, “independent subexpression”. Although Python’s `re` library does not implement either possessive quantifiers — or, as far as I can discern, independent subexpressions — [Matthew Barnett’s replacement `regex` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) does support both of those, along with uncountably many other niceties as well. `regex` may replace `re` in a near-future Python release, so the more testing the better.

Comment: @tchrist - I often browse SO from my phone, and occasionally feel compelled to write an answer from there, despite the relative inconvenience of looking things up from the phone interface, so I apologize for the haste. Fixed.

Comment: I took your advice (getting the enums first and than iterate over the matches in a loop) and it works like a charm, thanks.